# Starter BOOKS On Data Analytics and Algorithms in Computer Science

Tags: database, algorithms, data

Am Programmer cum Co-Founder of Start-up,Am a computer Science Graduate though am not good at Algorithms,I want to learn and sharp that side.Please suggest me some nice books for starters and Advance Level.

Answer (score 1):

A good reference bible is the CLRS Algorithms book. You will find this used as the textbook for the algorithms course at any major university. Its pretty heavy, but anything you need is in there somewhere.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Third-Thomas-Cormen/dp/0262033844](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262033844)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're looking for algorithms for.  If you're using an object-oriented language, most people hold "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" to be full of the main patterns you will definitely want to be familiar with.  But each programming domain and purpose is going to have its own algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

As [Raskolnikov](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62450/starter-books-on-data-analytics-and-algorithms-in-computer-science/62463#62463) said, Cormen is good. I also like [Skiena](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/)'s [Algorithm Design Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387948600).